# Built-In Character Casing functions in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, string

Are there any built-in functions in .Net that allow to capitalize strings, or handling proper casing? I know there are some somewhere in the Microsoft.VB namespace, but I want to avoid those if possible.

I'm aware of functions like string.ToUpper and string.ToLower() functions however it affects the entire string. I am looking to something like this:

```
var myString = "micah";
myString = myString.Format(FormattingOptions.Capitalize) //Micah
```

Comment: Why avoid the VB namespace? There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to throw another option into the mix. This will capitalize every word in the given string:

```
public static string ToTitleCase(string inputString)

{

   System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo =
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
   System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
   return textInfo.ToTitleCase(inputString.ToLower());

}
```

Comment: This is very nice. Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 4):

There's

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string str)
```

to capitalize every word in a string. [ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a free library available... [String Processing Library](http://www.vcskicks.com/components/string-library.php)

Answer (score 1):

This works in VB.NET

StrConv(Input, VbStrConv.ProperCase)